# C++ how to extend class from different file without headers

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I’m trying to do a basic polymorphism program and am having some problems.
I have 2 files, Currency.cpp and Dollar.cpp

Currency.cpp looks something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Currency{
/* code */
};
```

Dollar.cpp looks something like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dollar : protected Currency{
/* code /*
};
```

When I try to build paths between the files (command shift b on mac) it tells me that Currency is not recognized as a class (in Dollar.cpp that is). I’m not supposed to use header files as this is for an assignment that specifies so. What am I supposed to do?

I use vs code on a 2020 m1 Mac if that has anything to do with it

Edit:
Thanks for all the feedback. From what I can tell what I'm asking here isn't possible. This assignment is for a data structures and algorithms class that accepts multiple languages, so maybe the teacher is rusty in c++ or something. I'm just gonna use header files and the professor will just have to deal with it lol.

Comment: Put both in the same file? Or just write what a header file would look like at the top of `Dollar.cpp`. The preprocessor is really dumb, so `#include` literally means: Copy everything from that file right here

Comment: @Lala5th _"just write what a header file would look like at the top of `Dollar.cpp`"_ - that will most probably result in an ODR violation.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That would imply that you could never use header files to separate implementation. As long as the two translation units are not mixed (and it is implemented properly) there shouldn't be an issue. Again the preprocessor is dumb, so if you do it's very simple job, then you'll be just fine

Comment: The sad thing is the problem you are having is wholly manufactured and has absolutely nothing to do with the stated goal of learning about polymorphism. That makes it a pretty stupid assignment.

Comment: not sure why you don't want to use headers, it is standard practice. the only alternative would be to put all code inside a .cpp file. I don't recommend including .cpp files with  the preprocessor, it opens for all kinds of funny errors.

Comment: @AndersK Sounds like it might be another (flawed) assignment (sigh).  OP needs to answer my question, otherwise we're going nowhere.

Comment: Oh, he already said, my bad.  I would ignore that requirement and do it anyway, trying to do this any other way is just horrible.

Comment: @Lala5th _"That would imply that you could never use header files to separate implementation"_ - I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly but I'm just saying that it'll _probably_ result in an ODR violation.

Comment: Ya this assignment is definitely weird. It's for a data structure / algorithm class that accepts c++ java and python, so maybe the teacher is just not completely versed in c++. This assignment has this specific instruction "For C++ students, code your class declarations and definitions in the same file."

Answer (score 5):

> I’m not supposed to use header files as this is for an assignment that specifies so.

The code will not work as shown. `Dollar.cpp` needs to know what the `Currency` class looks like in order to use it.

The *ideal* solution is to use a header file to share *declarations* across translation units, use the `.cpp` files to implement *definitions*, eg:

Currency.h:

```
#ifndef CurrencyH
#define CurrencyH

class Currency{
    /* code */
};

#endif
```

Currency.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Currency.h"
using namespace std;

// implement Currency's methods as needed...
```

Dollar.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Currency.h"
using namespace std;

class Dollar : protected Currency{
    /* code /*
};
```

But, since that is not an option for you, you have no choice but to copy the entire `Currency` class declaration into `Dollar.cpp` directly, and make sure it *exactly matches* the class declaration in `Currency.cpp` to avoid any [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) violations, eg:

Currency.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Currency{
    /* code */
};

// implement Currency's methods as needed...
```

Dollar.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Currency{
    /* code */
};

class Dollar : protected Currency{
    /* code /*
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I already knew how to use headers but this made me sure that this assignment is just flawed.